# Using document.execCommand('copy') in mobile

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

Is there a way to copy to mobile clipboard? I've been researching for days but haven't found a good solution. Clipboard.js doesn't seem to work on mobile, giving me an error "no support :("

I'm currently using the following function:

```
function copytext(text) {
    var textField = document.createElement('textarea');
    textField.innerText = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textField);
    textField.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    textField.remove();
}
```

Works like a charm on chrome on my desktop. But on chrome mobile, nothing gets copied.

Is there a solution out there?

Comment: What version of Chrome and what mobile device? It's supposedly available in mobile Chrome 42+ and mobile Firefox 41+, presumably both Android.

Comment: Weird. I'm on the most recent version. Here's a live page with the copy link button: http://www.trailerpuppy.com/trailers/captain-america-civil-war-trailer-8c60bffa-6534-4496-bb89-e6ffc8684e2a

Comment: Working on my end, Chrome 49.0.* for Android. I'm guessing you're using iOS Chrome?

Comment: Ah.. yeah I think my version may be outdated. It was the most recent version available on my iOS version.. But I need to update iOS. Thanks for troubleshooting.

Comment: Chrome for iOS is basically just an alternative app for the same rendering and JavaScript API as the built-in WebKit for Safari. Unless iOS Safari supports it, iOS Chrome and Firefox probably won't either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), `document.execCommand('copy')` is available in the following mobile browsers:

- Chrome for Android 42+
- Firefox Mobile (Gecko) 41+

Note that this does not include the iOS Chrome or Firefox, which per-Apple's requirement, both must use the iOS supplied WebKit. Until iOS Safari supports it, iOS Chrome and iOS Firefox probably cannot.

**Update:**

Safari on iOS 10+ supports cut and copy

Comment: thanks for the link, you can update that as of now the copy feature is available for all browsers :)